# Fastest and Most efficient way to 'filter' huge number of JSON files

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have around 20000 (compressed) JSON files, each containing an average of 100,000 lines, each line a JSON object of anywhere from 1kb to 12kb.

I'm using EMR to parse this data and extract necessary keys. Since this is plenty of data, I'm looking for the best possible way to parse it.

I'm interested in only ~8-10% of the lines in each file; which contain a particular key `reqKey1`. Along with this, they must contain a particular key-value combination: `reqKey2: True`.

What could be the fastest way to extract the required data from this? The easiest thing to think of would be to simply parse each like, look for the key `reqKey1` and check the value of `reqKey2`. But I guess parsing every line would be very expensive especially considering >90% of the lines will be discarded eventually.

Any tips?

Comment: How long does your current solution take?  What compression scheme is used?

Comment: You can't know which lines to discard without reading the file; unless you know some other information about the data set? For example, the target is after X number of lines.

Comment: Yes, but the process of discarding the lines could be something that can be optimized. I'm working on obtaining some timing info; my EMR cluster is throwing up a couple of issues. I'll update the question in a bit.

Comment: What platform is this on?

Comment: parsing JSon is more efficient in c and c++.

Comment: You could try a regex match before actually parsing the line as json and e.g. exclude lines that match `"reqKey2": True` right away. I'd guess that might be somewhat faster than filtering the parsed json... not sure though °°